# Url rewrite in CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, url, url-rewriting

My url is like websitename/package?some-text
some-text is actually alias and using this I fetch values from db
i want to see my url like  websitename/some-text
I am using CodeIgniter framework and package is a controller 
Please help me..

Comment: You can use htaccess for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try by using htaccess file like below

Redirect 301 /package?some-text http://websitename.com/some-text

You can use [this](http://www.rapidtables.com/web/tools/redirect-generator.htm) site for generating htaccess rules.

**EDIT**

Please change the content of htaccess to

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/package?some-text [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /some-text#%1 [L]
```

**EDIT - 2**

You can also try to do this with in tyhe codeIgniter routes.php file, like

```
$route['some-text'] = "package_some-text";
$route['default_controller'] = "web";
$route['404_override'] = 'web/not_found';
```

Comment: Thanks Hari . Its working. But its redirecting right now . I need to load contents in websitename/package?some-text when i type http://websitename.com/some-text. The url should be http://websitename.com/some-text

Comment: @SumeshPs Please see the Editted answer

Comment: I tried like this..        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/mysite/test [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /mysite/index.php/package_categories#%1 [L].  but not working for me

Comment: Is  /mysite/index.php/package_categories URL loading properly?

Comment: I put that code at my route.php file under config . Thats working perfectly . Thank you very much . God bless you